# How exactly does NOT EXISTS work in SQL?

Tags: sql, exists, not-exists

I've googled and looked at examples but can't find one that will explicitly explain how one works.

So I'm looking at this example.

Here are the following relations

- Student (ssn, name, address, major)
- Course (code, title)
- Registered (ssn, code)

And the following lists courses in which all students are registered.

```
Select 
    code, title
From 
    course c
Where 
    not exists (Select ssn from student s
                where not exists (select ssn from registered r
                                  where c.code = r.code and s.ssn = r.ssn ));
```

So how does this example actually work? Do we start from the outer or inner part? I'm just really confused on how the not exists part works too. I mean I understand it returns true if an empty set is returned or false if a value is returned. But I just need someone to thoroughly explain an example for me. (For instance this one).

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the execution start from inner to outer has it is a subquery

```
    Select code, title From course c Where not exists (
 Select ssn from student s where not exists (
select ssn from registered r where c.code = r.code and s.ssn =r.ssn ));
```

Based on your query it explain that return me the title and code from course table if there record in student table and student record is not there in registered table

Hope you understood

Comment: Thanks for answer Fahim. I think that I kind of follow but I'm still a little confused on this. I'm not sure why I'm finding this confusing :(. So if we start from the most inner, then we find all the SSN from the registered table where c.code=r.code & s.ssn=r.ssn. So then I guess we execute the next part, which is Select ssn from student s? or how does it work. Does it execute the select ssn from registered r where c.code = r.code and s.ssn =r.ssn )); for each student? Sorry for all the questions. Thanks.